# How can I increase the precision of the Google Geocoder Response?

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder

I have written two tests using the Google Geocoder:
One test simply requests the geopoints for a given address,

while the second takes geo points retrieved from google and tries to get an address.

My problem is that in the address google returns back to me with it's own (geo points) is not the same!
To sum up; 
My address: Hirtenstraße 4, 10178 Berlin, Germany

Google's geopoints: lat = 52.5257827,lng =  13.4113952

Google returned address: Hirtenstraße 4, 10178 Berlin, Germany

My question: is there a way to control (increase) the precision of the geo point results you get back?

```
// ####### example code below################################################
@Test
 public void testGetPoints() throws IOException {
    final Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder();

    String land = "Germany";
    String city = "Berlin";
    String streetAddress = "4 Hirtenstraße";
    String postcode = "10178";

    String fullAddress = streetAddress + ",+" + postcode + ",+" + city + ",+" + land;
    fullAddress = fullAddress.replace(" ", "+");

    GeocoderRequest geocoderRequest = new GeocoderRequestBuilder().setAddress(fullAddress).setLanguage("en").getGeocoderRequest();
    GeocodeResponse geocoderResponse = geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest);
    ArrayList<GeocoderResult> addresses = new ArrayList<>(geocoderResponse.getResults());

    for (GeocoderResult r : addresses) {
        System.out.println(r.getGeometry().getLocation());
    }
}


@Test
public void testGeocoder() throws IOException {
    ArrayList<GeocoderResult> addresses = new ArrayList<GeocoderResult>();
    GeocodeResponse geocoderResponse;
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder();

    // geo points we get from the previous test
    BigDecimal lat = new BigDecimal(52.5257827);
    BigDecimal lng = new BigDecimal(13.4113952);

    GeocoderRequest geocoderRequest = new GeocoderRequestBuilder().setLocation(new LatLng(lat, lng)).setLanguage("en").getGeocoderRequest();

    geocoderResponse = geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest);
    addresses.addAll(geocoderResponse.getResults());

    for (GeocoderResult r : addresses) {
        System.out.println(r.getFormattedAddress());
        // first value returns:
        // Hirtenstraße 5, 10178 Berlin, Germany !!!!!  not 4!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That result is:

```
"location_type": "RANGE_INTERPOLATED"
```

So it won't be precise, it is interpolated.  You need a geocoder result that has "ROOFTOP" results, but Google's Geocoder doesn't have them (yet).

full geocoder response:

```
{
  "address_components": [
    {
      "long_name": "4",
      "short_name": "4",
      "types": [
        "street_number"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Hirtenstraße",
      "short_name": "Hirtenstraße",
      "types": [
        "route"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Mitte",
      "short_name": "Mitte",
      "types": [
        "sublocality_level_1",
        "sublocality",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Berlin",
      "short_name": "Berlin",
      "types": [
        "locality",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Berlin",
      "short_name": "Berlin",
      "types": [
        "administrative_area_level_1",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "Germany",
      "short_name": "DE",
      "types": [
        "country",
        "political"
      ]
    },
    {
      "long_name": "10178",
      "short_name": "10178",
      "types": [
        "postal_code"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "formatted_address": "Hirtenstraße 4, 10178 Berlin, Germany",
  "geometry": {
    "bounds": {
      "Ka": {
        "H": 52.5257728,
        "j": 52.5257827
      },
      "Ga": {
        "j": 13.41138669999998,
        "H": 13.411395200000015
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "H": 52.5257827,
      "L": 13.411395200000015
    },
    "location_type": "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
    "viewport": {
      "Ka": {
        "H": 52.5244287697085,
        "j": 52.5271267302915
      },
      "Ga": {
        "j": 13.410041969708459,
        "H": 13.412739930291536
      }
    }
  },
  "partial_match": true,
  "place_id": "EipIaXJ0ZW5zdHJhw59lIDQsIDEwMTc4IEJlcmxpbiwgRGV1dHNjaGxhbmQ",
  "types": [
    "street_address"
  ]
}
```